# Why is induction an axiom?

Tags: induction, integers, axioms

If natural numbers are defined as $\mathbb{N} = \{1\} \cup \{n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and we know that $P(1)$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb N,P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, then $S = \{ n \mid P(n)\} = \{1\} \cup \{n + 1 \mid n \in S\} = \mathbb N$, meaning that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n)$.

In this case why do we need induction (or the equivalent well-ordering principle) as an axiom?

Comment: I don't think induction is an axiom, - it is a theorem, and I distinctly remember it even having a second (quite odd) form...

Comment: @gt6989b: Wikipedia calls it an axiom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Axiom_of_induction

Comment: It says that "it can be formalized as a 2nd order axiom" -- it does not *have* to be but *can* be, so you can choose this definition and it is equivalent to the other one...

Comment: I don't follow you. What does "why do we need induction as an axiom" have to do with what you said in your first paragraph? Are you saying that **induction shouldn't be an axiom, because it's true**? So according to you we shouldn't have axioms at all? Or we should only have false axioms like the Axiom of Determinacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is circular, you use $\mathbb{N}$ to define $\mathbb{N}$. To construct the set $\mathbb{N}$, use the Peano's Axioms, and the fifth axiom is percisely the Induction Principle: If $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is a set such that $0 \in S$ and $n \in S \Rightarrow n+1 \in S$ then $S=\mathbb{N}$.

The Induction Principle and the Principle of well-ordering are equivalent.

Comment: It's not circular, I'm defining $\mathbb{N}$ as the unique set for which that equality is true. But I see what you mean, when I define it that way, I'm implying the axiom of induction

Comment: @user485573 What is $n+1$? Under a reasonable definition, there are many sets that satisfy your given equation. You need to strengthen your definition to ensure uniqueness.