# Why does induction have to be an axiom?

Tags: induction, axioms, peano-axioms

I noticed that there is an axiom that says that if $S(n)\implies S(n+1)$, and $S(1)$ is true, then $\forall n \in \Bbb N, S(n).$

My question is why is this an axiom? why can't we derive this from the other axioms?

Comment: Google Search the Peano Postulates

Comment: Depends on what other axioms you have ... are you thinking of a specific set of 'other axioms'?

Comment: We can derive it, if our other axioms include Well Ordering.  It's just up to us to decide whether we want to deduce this from that, or that from this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is induction an axiom?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449853/why-is-induction-an-axiom)

Comment: Sure, it seems so obvious logically if you already have the naturals. Note that if you're talking about a subset of the Peano axioms, you don't have $\Bbb{N}$ yet to refer to.

Comment: Hint: can you make your own *logically consistent* number system that agrees with all the non-induction axioms, that you then extend with a new number called "fred" that obeys all the axioms but is not a successor of any number and is not zero?  If you can do that, then induction does not work in your new number system, because proving that something works for zero, and that it works for any successor of any number, **does not prove that the proposition holds for fred**. That's sufficient to show that induction cannot be proven from the other axioms.

Comment: @user1390 Sorry, I don't see it. The model in Bram28's answer is based on $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ q \}$, which could be well-ordered by "appending" q after the natural order of $\mathbb{N}$: 1, 2, 3, ..., q. Yet his induction still fails. Maybe you need a well-ordering that is in some way compatible with the arithmetic?

Comment: @BhavinChirag It might very well be a duplicate of *some* other question about induction being an axiom, but not of the one you mentioned. This question here just plainly asks "Why does it have to be an axiom?", whereas the other one asks what is wrong with their shot at deriving it from the other axioms. Those yield quite different answers.

Comment: I wasn't very specific, but I meant to say that the two are equivalent the standard construction for $\mathbb{N}$. Specifically we need that every element is a successor except 0.  This is not true from Bram28's example.  

Basically if you assume WO, you can take the set of cases where the inductive statement fails and find the least element.  By the basis case, this isn't everything so that least element can be written as a successor.  Then we get a contradiction since S(n) implies S(n+1).  The proof in the other direction is not long either.

Comment: @user1390 Thanks, that makes more sense to me.

Comment: @mastov: See [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10033/1550) for a proper explanation. You may also want to read some of the other posts linked from my profile such as "Naturals" and "Circularity in mathematics" and "Building blocks".

Comment: @user21820 Is this an answer to something I said?

Answer (score 58):

If you're looking at the Peano axioms for Arithmetic, and by 'the other axioms' you mean:

$1. \bf{\forall x \ \neg s(x) = 0}$

$2. \bf{\forall x \forall y (s(x) = s(y) \rightarrow x = y)}$

$3. \bf{\forall x \   x+0=x}$

$4. \bf{\forall x \forall y \  x+s(y)=s(x+y)}$

$5. \bf{\forall x \   x\cdot0=0}$

$6. \bf{\forall x \forall y \  x\cdot s(y)=(x \cdot y) + x}$

then no, we can't derive the axiom of induction, which I'll formalize as:

$\bf{(S(0) \land \forall x (S(x) \rightarrow S(s(x))))\rightarrow \forall x \ S(x)}$  (I include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, so base is $\bf{S(0)}$)

and where it is understood that $S(x)$ is any first-order logic formula with $x$ as a free variable. Indeed, the above isn't so much a single axiom or even a single statement, but it is an axiom *schema* representing an infinite number of axioms: for each formula that you use for $S(x)$ you obtain a separate axiom/statement that is an instantiation of this schema.

So, the question is: does any instantiation of this axiom schema (using only $s$,$+$,and $\cdot$ as non-logical symbols) logically follow from the 6 Peano axioms above?

The answer is no. For example, take $\bf{S(x): s(x) \not = x}$

By axiom $1$, we have $\bf{\neg s(0)=0}$, and hence we have $\bf{S(0)}$

Also, if we have $\bf{S(k)}$, i.e. if we have $\bf{s(k) \not = k}$, then if it would be true $\bf{s(s(k)) = s(k)}$, then by Axiom 2 we have $\bf{s(k)=k}$, which contradicts $\bf{S(k)}$, and so we have $\bf{s(s(k)) \not = s(k)}$, i.e. $\bf{S(s(k))}$

OK, so with this $S(x)$, we have $\bf{S(0) \land \forall x (S(x) \rightarrow S(s(x)))}$ simply by virtue of Axioms 1 and 2 alone.

But, we do not necessarily have $\bf{\forall x \ S(x)}$

Consider a model with domain $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ q \}$, i.e. the natural numbers together with some 'extra' element $q$.

Interpret the $\bf{0}$ constant symbol as $0$

Interpret the $\bf{s}$ function symbol as a function $f$ for which $f(n)=n+1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and for which $f(q)=q$

Interpret the $\bf{+}$ function symbol as a function $g$ for which $g(m,n)=m+n$ and $g(m,q)=g(q,n)=g(q,q)=q$ for any $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Interpret the $\bf{\cdot}$ function symbol as a function $h$ for which $h(m,n)=m\cdot n$ for any $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, for which $h(0,q)=h(q,0)=0$, and for which $h(m,q)=h(q,n)=h(q,q)=q$ for any $m, n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{ 0 \}$

Then it is easily verified that all $6$ axioms are satisfied, and hence under this interpretation it is true that $\bf{S(0) \land \forall x (S(x) \rightarrow S(s(x)))}$.  But, since $f(q)=q$, it is false that $\bf{\forall x \ s(x) \not = x}$. Hence, it is false that $\bf{S(0) \land \forall x (S(x) \rightarrow S(s(x))))\rightarrow \forall x \ S(x)}$, i.e. the axiom of induction would not hold under this interpretation. Therefore, the axiom of Induction does not follow from axioms $1$ through $6$.

Comment: Minor detail:  I think you want $h(q,0) = 0$ (as you wrote) but $h(q,\cdot) = h(\cdot ,q) = q$ for any other choice.  (And the choice of  $h(0,q)$ is actually irrelevant:  $h(0,q) = h(0,S(q)) = h(0,q) + 0$ is the only axiom to worry about, and is true regardless of the value of $h(0,q)$.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, that was a typo, thanks! And you're right, you can set $h(0,q)$ to anything, so I might as well save some typing by setting it to $0$ (which will save commutation as well)

Comment: Nitpick: I think we need to state $h(q,q)=q$, as already done for $g(q,q)=q$.

Comment: @chi Quite!  I'll add that, thanks!

Comment: But the thing is, under your interpretation, axiom of induction would still hold for **natural** numbers, that is all elements except q. Is there any example, where axiom of induction does not hold for natural numbers?

Comment: @mercury0114 For the natural numbers, the axiom of induction holds of course.  But the OP's question was: can we derive it from 'the other axioms', by which I assumed the 6 basic axioms for arithmetic as indicated at the start of my Answer. And no, as I demonstrate in my Answer, you cannot derive it from those 6 axioms .... which is why thew axiom of Induction needs to be added as a further axiom if your goal is to axiomatize the natural numbers.

Comment: Let me add some food for thought: Define the set $N$ as $0 \in N$ and if $x \in N$ then $s(x) \in N$. Now define induction as: $\forall P. P(0) \vee [x \in N \vee P(x) \implies P(s(x))] \implies \forall y \in N. P(y)$, my question, can this definition of induction be derived from the other axioms?

Comment: @mercury0114 Good question ... first, since that statement quantifies over a predicate, it's a second-order logic statement ... and it would require second-order logic derivation rules to derive it. Second, you'd need to add the definition of the set N as an axiom. This requires set-theoretic language, and associated set-theoretic axioms. And please note that you need to define N as the set of all *and only* those objects that can be generated through the recursive process mas indicated. This can be done, but is not easy.

Comment: @mercury0114  (cont'd) But when you have done so, then yes, you can derive it. In fact, you don't need any of the other 6 axioms dealing with Peano arithmetic at all. Indeed, intuitively, the very way you define set N should make the truth of the inductive axiom trivially true. The difficult issue is to define N in the first place.

Comment: Could you add to your answer emphasizing that the axiom the asker wrote is just *one* of the induction axioms, and that there is actually a whole schema, with one axiom for each first-order predicate S? This is often missed, but it is an important point, and I don't want it to be buried on this thread. Thanks! =)

Comment: @user21820 Done!

Answer (score 19):

The Peano Postulates describe what we want the natural numbers to look like. One thing we want is for the natural numbers to be one continuous stream

```
0, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

and not made up of several infinite sequences like

```
0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 0', 1', 2', ...
```

where every number has a successor and arithmetic works fine, but if you start counting somewhere in the first sequence you'll never arrive at any number in the second (primed) sequence.

The induction axiom forbids this situation by saying that for every number N, if you start counting from 0 you'll eventually reach N.

Comment: But [nonstandard models of PA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) exist which contain numbers which can't be so reached.

Comment: @JohnColeman Because the axiom of induction is not a first-order axiom, but a second-order one. Nonstandard models of PA are only elementary-equivalent to PA, not isomorphic. In other words - the axiom of induction indeed doesn't hold in nonstandard models.

Comment: @Itai There are two flavors of PA. One has a second order axiom of induction (which quantifies over sets) and the other a first order axiom schema of induction (in terms of predicates). OP isn't sufficiently precise to be sure, but their formulation in terms of $S(n)$ seems closer to the first order formulation than the second order formulation.

Comment: As I understand it though, nonstandard models refer to models of all axioms except the axiom (or axiom schema) of induction, so I'm not entirely sure what you meant by the original comment. It seems you are saying the same thing as is said in this answer, namely - "the axiom (or axiom schema) of induction is required so we can tell apart the standard model from nonstandard ones"...

Comment: @Itai Nonstandard models of PA satisfy the axiom schema of induction. Perhaps you are thinking of [Robinson Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic).

Comment: Ah, that's probably it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Ultimately the way we prove (usually) that a given axiom $\alpha$ isn't already a consequence of a set of axioms $T$ is by constructing a [**model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)#Structures_and_first-order_logic) *(I've linked to a formal definition, but you should skip it at first read - just think of a model informally, as "a thing satisfying the axioms")* of $T$ in which $\alpha$ fails. The most famous example of this is the [parallel postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate), which was proved to be independent of the remaining postulates of Euclid via [the construction of non-Euclidean geometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry).$^1$

Now in our case - I presume you're talking about the theory PA - our theory has two parts:

- An "algebraic" part, asserting that the natural numbers form a discrete ordered semiring.
- The induction axioms (a "set-theoretic" part).

It's not trivial to construct a model of the former in which the latter can fail, but they exist; see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1617844/28111) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803007/how-does-induction-fail-in-computable-nonstandard-models).

(Incidentally, once we include induction it becomes very difficult to construct models other than the usual one - we can see this, for example, in [Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem). With Tennenbaum in mind, we actually have a very easy recipe for cooking up discrete ordered semirings where induction fails: simply pick any "easily describable" discrete ordered semiring not isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$!)

---

$^1$I don't want to give the wrong impression here: independence results can be extremely difficult to establish, since the more complicated a theory is the harder its models are to describe in general. For example, at a much more advanced level this is also how we show that the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) is independent of [the usual axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), assuming the latter are consistent of course. Godel constructed [the inner model $L$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) and showed that it satisfied CH; later, Cohen developed [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) and showed that it could produce models where CH fails *(as well as models where CH holds, but the former is more impressive: besides being the remaining missing piece, one consequence of Godel's work was that establishing the consistency of the failure of CH is in a precise sense harder than establishing the consistency of CH)*. However, unlike non-Euclidean geometry and slightly unusual discrete ordered semirings, models of set theory are hideously complicated and there's no good way to describe these results without *lots* of technical work.

Answer (score 7):

It is maybe helpful to think in terms of formal proofs. For each particular $n$, a formal proof of $S(n)$ looks something like this:

$$\begin{align*} 
S(1), S(1) &\implies S(2)\\
S(2), S(2) &\implies S(3)\\
&\vdots \\
S(n-1), S(n) &\implies S(n)
\end{align*}$$

which we use *modus ponens* to go from each line to the next, and $S(i) \implies S(i+1)$ is short-hand for a formal proof of this statement, using the other (non-inductive) axioms in your chosen system.

But although we can give a formal proof of $S(n)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is nothing above that comes close to a formal proof of the formula $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) S(n)$.

To put it another way: formal proofs are finite objects, so there is no sense in which we can 'roll-up' the proofs for each particular $n$ into a single formal proof dealing with all $n$ at once. Instead we need the axiom of induction.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that without an axiom, there is a difference between

$$\text{You can have as many apples as you want.$^*$}$$
and $$\text{You can have infinitely many apples.}$$

$^*$$\scriptsize\text{(finite amount implied)}$

Comment: Even with induction, there is a difference between those things. Van der Waerden's theorem is a good example; we can prove (by induction!) that in any finite coloring of the naturals, there are arithmetic progressions as large as you want; but there are not necessarily infinite arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @MishaLavrov This is absolutely true, but I wanted a short and intuitive answer. In the end, it is definitely not perfect. I am still thinking of a better way to put it.